# How to control speed of slider in react-native-image-slider-box lib

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image

Everyone.
I am building the expo app and added the slider image by using react-native-image-slider-box npm lib.
But there is no idea to change the slider speed.....
Is there any solution for this and It would be great to use another lib for this.

Thanks.

```
import { SliderBox } from 'react-native-image-slider-box';


        <SliderBox
          images={sliderImages}
          autoplay
          circleLoop
          disableOnPress
          paginationBoxVerticalPadding={30}
          ImageComponentStyle={{
            width,
            height: normalizeSize(450)
          }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

react-native-image-slider-box is using react-native-snap-carousel to edit the Slider follow the steps **node_modules -> react-native-image-slider-box -> dist**  and edit SliderBox.js file and add

```
 <Carousel
        ......
        autoplayInterval={15000}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```html
<SliderBox
autoplayInterval={3000}
........
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

*control imgae slider speed and loopcircle*
***no need        autoplayInterval={1000}***

```
<SliderBox
autoplay
circleLoop
resizeMethod={'resize'}
resizeMode={'cover'}
paginationBoxStyle={{
  position: "absolute", 
}}
/>
```